# Can't get dojo.place to work

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

For whatever reason, this little piece of dojo isn't working. I have to admit though, I am fairly new to dojo.

```
dojo.query("#addIngredient").onclick(function(){
        var ingredients = dojo.query(".ingredients");
        var cloned = dojo.clone(ingredients);
        dojo.place( cloned, dojo.query("#placeBefore"), "before");
     });
```

In firebug, the dojo.query and dojo.clone events seem to be working fine, it just gets confused at dojo.place. Here's the html:

```
<input type="button" id="addIngredient" value="Add ingredient" />
  <div class="ingredients">
    //some code
  </div>
  <div id="placeBefore" style="clear:both; height: 1px;"></div>
```

**Any idea why this isn't working?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter to `dojo.place` expects a domNode or id, not a NodeList (which is what you're providing it, since you're using `dojo.query` there).

You can easily simplify that line of code to the following and it ought to work:

```
dojo.place(cloned, "placeBefore", "before");
```

Reference: http://www.dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo.html#dojo.place